# Resolve circular include of 3 classes in C++

Tags: c++, dependencies, include, header-files

I have 3 classes which I am going to refer to as A, B and C (names in this example are arbitrary).
All 3 of these classes consist of a header-file and a cpp-file each.

I have the following dependencies:

- A needs to know B as A has a member of type B
- B needs to know A and C as B has members of both types
- C needs to know A as C has a member of type A

I have tried out several options already (include this header here, forward-declaration of class there), but compilation was never succesful. I also couldn't extract any helpful information from answers to problems which solved circular inclusion problems between only 2 classes.

EDIT:
Here a minimal (and hopefully sufficient) example of my current setup:
A.h

```cpp
class A {
private:
    B myB;
};
```

B.h

```cpp
class B {
private:
    A* myA;
    C myC;
};
```

C.h

```cpp
class C {
private:
    A* myA;
}
```

I should perhaps also note that B::myA and C::myA are always going to point to the same A-instance.

Comment: `I have tried out several options already (include this header here, forward-declaration of class there), but compilation was never succesful.` Forward declarations are the way to go, we need an [MCVE].

Comment: Show us the (possibly abbreviated) declarations and definitions for your classes, and I'm 100% sure somebody here will give you a solution to your problem (or maybe more than one solution).

Comment: We really need to see a clear example of what you're trying to do, especially in regards to which members are pointers/references vs whole objects. At the moment I could read you explanation as wanting for each A to contain a B and then for each B to contain an A which isn't going to work since that leads to infinity.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes)

Comment: @TheUndeadFish The requested example has been added.

Comment: The headers for class `B` and `C` don't need or want to include the header for `A`. The header for class `A` needs to include the header for class `B`

Comment: Per drescherjm: possible duplicate of [Resolve build errors due to circular dependency amongst classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As class `C` only includes a *pointer* to class `A`, it doesn't need the full *definition* for either `A` or `B` (which it doesn't use); so, just a statement *declaring* `A` as a class will suffice:

C.h

```cpp
class A; // Declare that A is a class - then we can have a pointer to it...
class C {
private:
    A* myA;
}
```

Class `B` needs the *definition* of `C`, because it includes an *instance* of `C`; and, like class `C`, simply declaring `A` as a class (as is done already in `C.h`) will do:

B.h

```cpp
#include "C.h" // Note: This header already declares "A" as a class!
class B {
private:
    A* myA;
    C myC;
};
```

Class `A` needs the *definition* of `B`, as it contains an *instance* of `B`. But note that `B.h` already includes `C.h`:

A.h

```cpp
#include "B.h"
class A {
private:
    B myB;
};
```

Note that any other files that use one or more of `A`, `B` and `C` need only include the `A.h` header, as this will itself include the others.

Comment: Thank you very much, after applying your solution to my project and additionally including A.h in C.cpp it was compiled without issues.